# insert a component without disturb existing sibling in React

Tags: reactjs, insert

I created a component, "MyClass" (say "MyClass1"), into "container" in the following way

```
        class MyContainer extends React.Component{
            add(c, id) {
                ReactDOM.render(
                <div id={id}>{React.createElement(c)}</div>, document.getElementById("container"))
            }
            componentDidMount() {
                this.add(MyClass, "MyClass1");
            }
              render() {
                return (
                      <div id="container">

                      </div>
                );
              }
        }
```

Now I like to insert another "MyClass" (say "MyClass2") as another child of "container" without disturb the existing sibling (MyClass1):
the state of MyClass1 such as a dropdown selection should be remained after MyClass2 is inserted. So MyClass1 should not be remounted.

Any suggestion?

thanks

coolshare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you a push the components to be appended to a state array and assign `unique keys` to them, and they won't be rerendered again if there is no change in them

```
 class MyContainer extends React.Component{
        constructor(){
             super();
             this.state = {comp: []}
        }
        add = (c, id) => {
           var comp = [...this.state.comp];
            comp.push(<div key={id} id={id}>{React.createElement(c)}</div>);
            this.setState({comp})
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            this.add(MyClass, "MyClass1");
            this.add(MyClass, "MyClass2");
        }
          render() {
            return (
                  <div id="container">
                       {this.state.comp}
                  </div>
            );
          }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.